# Animation css not working in safari browser

Tags: css, reactjs, animation, safari, css-animations

```
animation: shine 4s linear infinite;
@keyframes shine {
        0% {
          background-position-x: -500%;
        }
        100% {
          background-position-x: 500%;
        }
      }
```

I use this style in react js web page. Its work all browser except safari browser i dont know why.

**Safari browser didn't display that animation text.**

Any one help to solve this problem

Comment: Please provide an example of your problem. Like this, it's just guesswork.

Comment: That animation text didn't display.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. In Safari when you use Keyframes you need to use the whole percentage:

this won't work:

```
@-webkit-keyframes shine{
    0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    5% { -webkit-transform: rotate(-14deg); }
    10% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
}
```

this will:

```
@-webkit-keyframes shine{
    0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    5% { -webkit-transform: rotate(-14deg); }
    10% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
}
```

Don't know why but that's the way Safari works! :)

Comment: But i used 0% and 100% in keyframes

Comment: use @-webkit-keyframes to support safari browser